# Domain not accessing correct files in Apache2 virtual hosts

Tags: apache2

I have 3 domains hosted on my Ubuntu server running Apache2 as DNS I am using `cloudflare.example`, `abc.example` and `xyz.example` are accessing correct files that are inside `abc.example/public_html` and `xyz.example/public_html` folder but the third domain is accessing files from the root folder. Following is the content of my `domain.example` file which is found under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.example`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    ServerName domain.example
    ServerAlias www.domain.example

    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.example/public_html
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Try making your Directory directive match your document root.  `<Directory /var/www/domain.com/public_html/>` instead of `<Directory /var/www/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    ServerName domain.example
    ServerAlias www.domain.exaple

    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.example/public_html
    <Directory /var/www/domain.example/public_html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You had 2 Directory directives and either one pointed to your DocumentRoot.