# multiple virtual host in apache 2.22 on debian 7 … very strange and inexplicable behavior … someone can try to help me?

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, debian

I'm facing a configuration issue that's really diving me nuts ...

Basically I'm working as a sysadmin for a customer who use a single server to host many different site, to be more specific:

Server is:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.debian.org/"

Linux **xyz** 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u6 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Server built:   Aug 18 2015 09:50:52
```

Now, on top of this I've configured several different web sites at third level, say for example `abc.xyz.it`, `def.xyz.it`, `ghi.xyz.it`, and so on. Everything is working as expected until last week I've been asked to configure one of the virtual host to answer to different external query on slightly different URL redirecting them on the same `DocumentRoot`. It seems quite trivial, in fact I've managed to allow `qqq.xyz.it` (original virtual host), plus `qqqk.xyz.it` and `www.qqqk.xyz.it` putting the expected configuration in the original `/etc/apache2/sites-available/qqq` file; then a2dissite qqq, service apache2 reload, a2ensite qqq, and again service apache2 reload ...

As I said everything was working with no problem.

But after a couple of days the customer asked me to add also `www.qqq.xyz.it` ...

My first thought was that it's simply trivial, so I edited the `qqq` file adding a section also for this instance ... well, despite several trials I was completely unable to make it run ... it seems to me there is nothing different from what I've done for the other virtual hosts, but no success at all.

I paste below the actual content of qqq file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName qqq.xyz.it
DocumentRoot /var/www2/qqq
<Directory /var/www2/qqq>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    #AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dri-error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel error

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dri-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName www.qqq.xyz.it
DocumentRoot /var/www2/qqq
<Directory /var/www2/qqq>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    #AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dri-error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel error

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dri-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName qqqk.xyz.it
DocumentRoot /var/www2/qqq
<Directory /var/www2/qqq>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    #AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dri-error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel error

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dri-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName www.qqqk.xyz.it
DocumentRoot /var/www2/qqq
<Directory /var/www2/qqq>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    #AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dri-error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel error

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dri-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone have a guess? I've tried several changes in the order of the four section into the file, I've tried to use ServerAlias which doesn't work in any place into the file ... I've run out of ideas, maybe it's a simple stupid thing but as far as I've been trying so long maybe I cannot see it ....

P.S.: Just to make it clear, the following image shows what I get as a response:

[image: Response]

Comment: You are not using VirtualHost and Directory directives. Here is an example of a working configuration. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60461/domain-not-accessing-correct-files-in-apache2-virtual-hosts/60471#60471 You are correct that you can point several VirtualHosts to the same DocumentRoot.

Comment: Can you not use ServerAlias directive...

Comment: No, for some reason ServerAlias do not work a2ensite gives no error, but then I cannot reach site ....

Comment: Also regarding post webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60461/…, I haven't any public_html directory, unfortunately it's a wordpress site ...

Comment: Questions seeking troubleshooting that is [specific to your site](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic here since they're unlikely to help others in the future, they require a lot of back and forth dialog that does not fit well with the format of this site, and there can be other unknown factors (such as if the host and CNAME that you're trying to add resolves properly...).

Comment: @closetnoc It seems the question was just incorrectly formatted, the `VirtualHost` wrappers were hidden.

Comment: Have you also added the appropriate DNS CNAME record for the `www.qqq.xyz.it` host to resolve? The "Server not found" error suggests this is not the case, otherwise if the request reached your server you should at least be getting a default config returned (usually the first _host_ that's defined). (`ServerAlias` really should be working - repeating entire VirtualHost containers just to match another _host_ variation is not good and wholly unnecessary. The order can be important.)

Comment: @w3dk Thanks! I should have thought of that. Not sure why it did not occur to me. Cheers Mate!!